# How to define elements with any name but enforce specific attributes?

Tags: xsd

I have an XML that contains such definition:

```
<addr15 type="binary" size="1" data_characters="0,1,0,1">text 15</addr15>
<addr14 type="binary" size="1" data_characters="0,1,0,1">text 14</addr14>
<addr13 type="binary" size="1" data_characters="0,1,0,1">text 13</addr13>
<addr12 type="binary" size="1" data_characters="0,1,0,1">text 12</addr12>
<addr11 type="binary" size="1" data_characters="0,1,0,1">text 11</addr11>
```

As the elements' names are user defined (any valid string is ok), the attributes are mandatory.

How can I define an XSD to validate this?

Using `<xsd:any>` won't do the job - it can't validate the attributes.
Set `processContents` to `lax` or `strict` won't do the job also, as I can't supply the required XSD statements to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > the elements' names are user defined (any valid string is ok)
> > An XSD mainly describes the tag names in the document, and how they can be validly combined. So this XML format is going to be tricky to describe using an XSD.

Options (in order of my preference):

1. Change the tag name to `<addr>` and define a new required attribute 'addrNumber' to hold the 11,12,13,14,15. This would be easy to describe using an XSD.
2. Pre-declare all of the allowed `<addrNN>` tag names as global elements in your XSD. Disallow any tag names that are not pre-declared in the XSD (advanced users could add their own declarations to the XSD)
3. Continue to allow user-defined tag names. Define a global complex-type-with-simple-content that describes the attributes and the tag value. Every user-defined `<addrNN>` tag must include an xsi:type attribute that points to this global type. I think this will require an xsd:any with processContents='strict' to ensure that the xsi:type attribute gets strictly validated.

I will not go into details on each option, but I can supply further details if you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, option1 and 2 are invalid as "addr" is just an example, any string is supported (the user defines the element name). As of Option 3 - if the user will not supply the "xsi:type" in their XML, then no enforcement will happen, right? in that case, i have nothing to do here... the validation depends if the user co-operate

Comment: If you want to do XSD validation then it's not smart to allow users to choose their own tag names. If you cannot enforce the use of xsi:type then validation is optional, and at the user's discretion. I'm struggling to see the point of even trying to create an XSD at this point.

Comment: well, the user defines "variables" for later to use in a provided equation. each "variable" has a custom name (the XML element name) with specific attribute (definition) - so each variable define has to conform to a specific format while its name is arbitrary.